# Enable onContextMenu when auto link detection is present

Tags: android, listview, listitem, linkify

I have a list item view , and I add this properties

```
            android:autoLink="web|email|phone"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            autoUrlDetect="true"
```

but the problem is when an link is detected the context menu is not shown.

How can I have links in my item but still the context menu to keep on showing when the item is long pressed.

in my list item I have one layout and textview inside him nothing more

**EDIT**

if I set this *android:linksClickable*  to false like this

```
android:linksClickable="false"
```

then the context menu is shown, but I can not click the link :(

I want to be able to click the link, but also when I long press the item my menu to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a 2 days searching for solution I found it :-).

```
android:focusable="true"
```

to the item fix my problem